# Should search filter make use of getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

I have 115 div's that are 120x120 and each has a different background image. Each div has multiple class names that I use solely for the purpose of a search bar, using `getElementsByClassName`. For example think of 115 humans, but being able to write 'female' in the search will result in hiding all the males and only showing the females.

Is this the wrong way of doing a search filter? I set the divs to `display = "none"` to hide them and `block` if they are part of what's being searched. I'm just worried about using multiple empty class names as a search filter. Is it alright to do it this way or is there a more convenient way that's done specifically for something like this?

Comment: Of course the usual solution employs a database with scripting to apply queries. I think you have an interesting alternative.  I don't know enough to comment further, except to point out that compared to a database approach, it may be hard to scale this up, or apply it to future needs.  In other words, the answer depends on your future plans, at least partly.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! This is a pretty small project. As in, once it's done, it's done. I wont be constantly adding stuff to it. I don't EVER imagine going over 150 div's, it'll never happen. So would you think it's not big enough to worry about and it's fine the way it is? Thanks once again for your help

Comment: You mention databases.  Unless you want a big learning project, consider a lightweight program like [sqlLite.org](https://sqlite.org/about.html).  More [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZSZIfhzc3A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more data-based approach (I mean, they're all data-based... let's say it's more like a database) by keeping an array in JavaScript of your 115 records.  So you have a flat-file database, in effect.  If your javascript skills are good for that, it would facilitate using an approach that generates divs instead of hiding them -- which would solve the resources issue mentioned by Campari.

It's actually much more scalable than your current solution.  For one thing, you can keep the array in a separate `.js` or `.ini` doc for easy maintenance.

Comment: It'd be easy for me to do this approach since I already have the code in place, just have to removeChild instead of set display to none. But as I mentioned in the other comment, are you guys sure it's less load on the browser to constantly remove and re-generate <div>'s instead of just setting display to none? Thanks a lot for all your help, sorry to be a bother

Comment: The issue is whether the divs are *rendered.*  You may want to use a browser tool to see how the resources are being handled (example, Firebug).

Comment: Thank you for always being so helpful and even including a tool I can test resources out with. Even though I knew about it, it's still nice to be told all kinds of tips without having to ask. Thanks once again for all your help

Comment: You're so courteous, it's a pleasure.  About Firebug and such -- I find them hard to understand, mostly because the reporting is so deep.  Stick with it -- the benefits are huge.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an ingenious way of doing it but it really depends. Will it stay with 115 "items" or are you planning on adding more? Because if you are planning on adding more it'll probably not scale well. I think it's already too much, not because of the search method on itself but because you have **>100 hidden divs with background images eating up all the browser resources**.

What you *could* do is store your items in a database table with a field for the background image path, and a field for the keywords, and when you perform a search and display *only* those who have the matching keyword instead of hiding all those which *don't*.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. Even if I use a database don't I have to hide all the <div>'s using `display = "block";` each time so that it can then show the few that are being searched for? Otherwise how does it hide the ones being shown that are currently being filtered out?

Comment: Hate Names -- the usual approach generates the divs as needed instead of hiding them.

Comment: @HateNames I'd highly recommend not doing it that way. Let's say that at first it shows _all_ divs. Then, if you do a search it that specifies the divs you could remove them to take the load off the browser. And "generate" them again if you need to with JavaScript.

Comment: @Smandoli -- I see, I'm currently looking into databases to gain more knowledge in that area. I must ask though, isn't generating 115 <div>'s just as bad? I mean let's say a person searches a name, deletes it completely, searches another, and so on several times. Every time they delete the entire search filter, it has to regenerate all 115 <div>'s to show, correct? Wouldn't loading them at start and then hiding them be less load on the browser overall? Sorry for all the questions, I'm just really curious to learn more about things. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Campari --Same thing as I mentioned above, isn't removing tons of <div>'s and adding them a much bigger load than just setting display to block and none? From what I understand display none tells the browser to completely ignore said element, thus it shouldn't even be taking up resources for those <div>'s ?

Comment: @HateNames Well, you are right about that. When you "reset" the search field and you have to generate 115 divs with background images, it will be quite heavy. But it's still better than having many divs hidden and wasting memory with no purpose.

Comment: Thanks again guys for your help. According to this: http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_render_tree_relation_to_the_DOM_tree if you search for the keyword "none" it says that those objects do not get added to the DOM tree and no box is even generated for them, where as `visiblity="hidden";` does what you are talking about. Either way I will follow Smandoli's advice and just test out performance with current method and then with a database. I might stick with the database either way since it's just a cleaner way of doing things. Thanks a lot for your help guys.